# SPARQL Query with Jena

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I have five Individuals in my .owl file which match with my SPARQL query, I tried the same query in "SPARQL Query" of Protege and it returns 5 individuals.
But when I tried that query in Eclipse using Jena library, it returns only 3 individuals !

My code :

```
    String file="....\\Ontology.owl";
    File f=new File(file);
    FileReader r=new FileReader(f);
    OntModel m=ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
    m.read(r,null);

    String req ="" +
        "PREFIX m: <http://www.NewOnto1.org/Ontology#>"+
        "PREFIX aut:<http://www.NewOnto1.org/Citations#AuthorCite>"+
        "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
        "SELECT ?AuthorName ?AuthorField"+
        "WHERE{"+
            "?x  rdf:type m:AuthorCite."+
            "?x m:AuthorName ?AuthorName."+
            "?x m:AuthorBelongsToField ?AuthorField."+
            "FILTER regex(str(?AuthorField),\""+field+"\")."+
        "}";

    com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query query = QueryFactory.create(req);

    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, m);
    com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet res = qe.execSelect();

    //ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, res, query);

    int leng=0;
    while(res.hasNext()){
        leng++;
        res.next();
    }
    System.out.println("Length : "+leng);
```

For more information, I want to get Individuals (Authors) which belongs to a specific research field (field).

Comment: You're at least going to run into issues with your string concatenation.  E.g., With `SELECT ?AuthorName ?AuthorField"+ "WHERE{` you're executing `select ?AuthorName ?AuthorFieldWHERE`, but you don't use a variable named "?AuthorFieldWHERE" in your query.  Be sure to insert spaces or newlines to get the query you actually expect.  (Try printing the query from Java to be sure.)

Comment: Also, rather than using string concatenation to inject the value of `field`, consider using [ParameterizedSparqlStrings](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ParameterizedSparqlString.html).  What would happen, for instance, if the value of `field` is `someField" . filter (really expensive operation ")`?

Comment: Also, the fact that you get more results in Protege could be because you have a *reasoner* running that could infer additional triples that the Jena won't (unless you add a reasoner).

Comment: It depends on which SPARQL plugin was used in Protege. Only the Snap SPARQL plugin supports reasoning. Just from the code above, the default OntModel should also consider some lightweight reasoning. But without seeing the data it's not possible to give some more help than @JoshuaTaylor already did.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor  and if a SPARQL query does not return all instances in Protege ? I mean, for example for that query normally it must return 5 instances, but it returns 3 instances !

Comment: @Dihya We don't have your ontology, and don't know what reasoner you're using in Protege.  Its impossible to know what a given query should return at a given time on a given endpoint.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor  
I finally found the problem : if an individual doesn't have a value for certain property which is selected in the query, then this individual will not be returned. So the solution is "OPTIONAL" :). Thank you so much